# Realtion mapping between two tables in different schema with code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using code first approach for my .net core project. We are using multiple schemas in single database.
We are maintaining models in different class library projects like Inventory,Sales,Finance etc ..

Model mapping is like ( note : below they are different name spaces)

```
[Table(name: "Product", Schema = "Inventory")]
public class Product 
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}


[Table(name: "Order", Schema = "Sales")]
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId{get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get;set;}
}
```

With in the schema i am able to add relation by using attribute. Now i want to add relation between these tables.
I have tried some tweaks but not working.
Any help is appreciated.

Update:  
DBcontext's  also different for each schema and they are placed in respective class library

Comment: Schema/namespaces doesn't really matter as soon as the db context (which in EF Core represents a database) has access to both classes. *"We are maintaining models in different class library projects"*, ok, but where is the db context which maps them to the database? How it looks like? Since there are no navigation properties, it requires fluent configuration having access to both classes.

Comment: ** DBContexts** are also in the same project where models resides. I have updated the question @IvanStoev

Comment: Then the problem most likely is the usage of different db contexts, which is not a good idea if they contain entities having relations with entities inside another context.  Because EF Core [includes them automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model) in the referencing db context model. As I commented, in EF Core 1 database should be 1 context. What are the problems (what is "not working")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have conflicting approaches in your current architecture:

On one hand, you have gone for a micro-services approach where each service is dealing with its own bounded context (e.g. Inventory, Sales, etc.).  This seems to be confirmed by your use of different database schemas, which can be viewed as logically different databases that happen to be deployed in a single physical database.  This is fine, and allows for future scaling / segregation where you might move the inventory data into its own database, for example.

On the other hand, you are trying to treat the datastore as a monolithic artefact where you can build table relationships across the bounded context boundary established by your micro-service approach.

If you wish to maintain your micro-services approach, which is perfectly reasonable, then you have to accept that you cannot rely on database-enforced referential integrity for table relationships that span entities in different micro-services.

You'd need a layer above that can retrieve data from separate micro-services and put them together into entities (preferably DTO entities, not the EF Data Entities used for code-first) that the consumer is looking for.

This layer would first retrieve Orders from the 'Sales' service, and then enumerate your Orders and retrieve the relevant Products from the 'Inventory' service and then map those into DTO entities that include navigation properties between OrderDTO and ProductDTO.

Your Order data entity should not have a virtual navigation property to "Product" but instead just hold a unique id of the Product that the Order relates to (not enforced as a database relationship).  Personally, I would go further and introduce a GUID Unique Identifier to the Product data class that can be used in the Order to uniquely identify the product.  That way, if you ever do migrate your Inventory tables to a new database, you don't have to worry about managing the Database Identity Column during that migration as the reference 'outside' of the Inventory service to the Product table would be the GUID Unique Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
public virtal Product Product {get;set;}
```

should be `virtual`

Also you need a navigation member in Product

```
[Table(name: "Product", Schema = "Inventory")]
public class Product 
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}


[Table(name: "Order", Schema = "Sales")]
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId{get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Typo is fine but still i am not able to add relation